# Python question, sending bulk email with different templates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I'm trying to automate my cold email sales process using Python. I basically want to put a bunch of information into a Google sheet. The column values in the Google Sheet are 
Name, Email, Company, Follow Up, News Item. 
Follow Ups from the following values (trying to figure out a way to track # of follow ups): Yes, #1, #2, No

I'm able to read the data from the Google Sheet and I was able to send an email.

Here's the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RkzEkCJ4kEbdsW4-LqyO8bKTKBm9XlXrMp49UxIpotQ/edit?usp=sharing)`.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import smtplib
import gspread
import pandas as pd
import pprint
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from emailsettings import USERNAME, PASSWORD
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheets = client.open('Example').sheet1

sh = client.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RkzEkCJ4kEbdsW4-LqyO8bKTKBm9XlXrMp49UxIpotQ/edit#gid=0')
sheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

data1 = sheet.get_all_values()

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',port=587,timeout=10)

smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)

INITIAL_MESSAGE = """
Hi {},

I came across your name while looking for contacts at {}. Huge fan of your work. 

I'm a person and I'm the founder and COO of this company. This Company is a full-service internet marketing agency, specializing in social media advertising. We've worked with Fortune 500 Company and many others. 

I'm reaching out because we've helped several companies with increasing their ROI and wanted to see if you were open to discussing your digital goals for 2019. 

Would you be open to hop on a quick call? Here's my schedule for the week. 

Looking forward to hearing from you. 

Thanks, Name

PS: Congrats on the {}
"""

FOLLOW_UP = """
Hey {}, how's {}? Hope you're doing awesome. 

Reading more about your background, super impressed - by the way, congrats on {}. 

I briefed my team about doing social media ads for {} and they're super excited. 

Can you meet sometime this week? Otherwise, here's my schedule so pick a time that works well for you. 

Cheers, 
Name
"""


SECOND_FOLLOW_UP="""
Hey {}, 

Just wanted to see how things were going at {}. Just wanted to check if you were still interested in chatting sometime about working with Company. 

If you're interested, send me over a list of times so we can chat. 

Thanks, Name

PS: Congrats on {}

"""

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',port=587,timeout=10)

smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)

iterdata = iter(data1)
next(iterdata)


for elem in data1:
    name, email, company, follow, news = elem

    if follow == 'No':
        subject = 'Hey {}, FOLLOW UP #1, {} and Company'.format(name, company, news)
        msg = FOLLOW_UP.format(name,company,company, news)



    elif follow =='1':
        subject = 'Hello, {}, FOLLOW UP #2'.format(company)
        msg = INITIAL_MESSAGE.format(name,company, news, company)


    elif follow =='2':
        subject = 'Hello again, {}, FOLLOW UP #3'.format(company)
        msg = SECOND_FOLLOW_UP.format(name,company, news)

    else:
        print('{}\n'.format(company))


    email_msg = 'Subject: {} \n\n {}'.format(subject, msg)    
    smtp.sendmail(from_addr=USERNAME ,to_addrs=email, msg=email_msg)

    print(email_msg)
smtp.quit()
```

It prints out "Company" and gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'subject' is not defined
```

My goal is to populate the spreadsheet with information about email, person, company, and news item. Once the spreadsheet is filled and the script is run, it would track the # of follow ups and generate an email based on several templates available.

I've heard this would be easier by creating classes and methods and attributions, but not really sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throws:

```
NameError: name 'subject' is not defined
```

Because of this line:

```
email_msg = 'Subject: {} \n\n {}'.format(subject, msg)
```

Notice you declare a var called `"subject"` in the `if` scope, not in the `else` (which should hold the "default" values to be used, no?)

This is also true for `msg` var which you later on format in:

```
email_msg = 'Subject: {} \n\n {}'.format(subject, msg)
```

Do something like:

```
...
else:
    subject = 'some default subject'
    msg = 'some default message'
    print('{}\n'.format(company))
```

[edit]

Or even better, declare the `subject` and `msg` with default values before you even start the `if` logic. When matched, override the values. This will ensure you use vars which are defined.

Something like:

```
for elem in data1:
    name, email, company, follow, news = elem

    subject = 'default subject' # ADD THIS LINE
    msg = 'default message' # ADD THIS LINE

    if follow == 'No':
        ...
```

[edit2]
To shorted your code (as you commented) try refactor to:

```
# mapping between 'follow' and (subject template and message template)
d = {'No': ('Hey {}, FOLLOW UP #1, {} and Company', FOLLOW_UP),
     '1': ('subject1', INITIAL_MESSAGE),
     '2': ('subject2', 'msg2'),
     }

for elem in data1:
    # elem should be namedTuple to hold all relevant data inside
    data = d.get(elem.follow, ('default subject', 'default message'))
    subject = data[0].format(**elem)
    msg = data[1].format(**elem)

    email_msg = 'Subject: {} \n\n {}'.format(subject, msg)
    smtp.sendmail(from_addr=USERNAME, to_addrs=elem.email, msg=email_msg)

    print(email_msg)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. 

I feel like the code could be cleaner though!

Comment: @AmateurPythonLearner - checkout my edit to the answer for shorter code option